# Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON flg=0x50200010 }

Tags: android, android-billing

I have gotten the following error in my app:

```
ANR( Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON flg=0x50200010 }) or Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON flg=0x50200010 (has extras)
```

I am unable to reproduce it and also unable to find proper solution.

Here is the log:

```
"main" tid=1 Native
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
   group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x768c04b8 self=0x6f75614c00
   sysTid=25685 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x6ffc094560
   state=S schedstat=( 70157029104 56848822182 116994 ) utm=4293 stm=2722 core=6 HZ=100
   stack=0x7fd1c5f000-0x7fd1c61000 stackSize=8MB
   held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000001eeec  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #01  pc 00000000000d7e24  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+148)
  #02  pc 00000000005205d0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::GoToRunnable(art::Thread*) (.llvm.265913428)+480)
  #03  pc 00000000005203ac  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JniMethodEnd(unsigned int, art::Thread*)+28)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (BinderProxy.java)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact (BinderProxy.java:1145)
  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.bindService (IActivityManager.java:4223)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1761)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService (ContextImpl.java:1701)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService (ContextWrapper.java:711)
  at com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl.startConnection (BillingClientImpl.java:326)
  at com.formula1.billing.BillingServiceImpl.reconnect (BillingServiceImpl.java:73)
  at com.formula1.billing.BillingServiceImpl.onBillingServiceDisconnected (BillingServiceImpl.java:69)
  at com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl$BillingServiceConnection.onServiceDisconnected (BillingClientImpl.java:1502)
- locked <0x08710b90> (a java.lang.Object)
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath (LoadedApk.java:1858)
  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run (LoadedApk.java:1873)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7050)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: From review. Your question should have your effort to solve the task. Here you post abstract question which will likely be deleted rather answered. Code is good, environment, screenshots, error codes (which you have). I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Yet marking question *Unsalvageable*.

Answer (score 0):

The most possible reason for this ANR is that you are doing something 'heavy' inside your receiver 'on receive'.
Unload heavy tasks from your receiver and if your receiver is in main thread do your stuff in a background worker.
Notice that this won't help if your receiver is in background.

Comment: It is likely not OP's own BroadcastReceiver that is causing this ANR crash.  It is probably in an included 3rd party dependency.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky how would one find such receiver? Such receiver should listen for the intent SCREEN_OFF shouldn't it?

Comment: @philk You mean `SCREEN_ON`?  I've gotten such ANR's because of 3rd party libraries, not because I had this receiver in my own code...